# Deserialize dynamic entity in Jackson from type in wrapper class

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class that I use to parse API requests:

```java
public class SkydropXApiResponse {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private SkydropXEntity attributes;

    public String getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getType() { return type; }

    public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }

    public SkydropXEntity getAttributes() { return attributes; }

    public void setAttributes(SkydropXEntity attributes) { this.attributes = attributes; }
}
```

`SkydropXEntity.java` is a class that is extended by concrete types, and has the following:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "parcels", value = SkydropXParcel.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "rates", value = SkydropXQuotation.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "addresses", value = SkydropXAddress.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "labels", value = SkydropXLabel.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "shipments", value = SkydropXShipment.class),

})
public abstract class SkydropXEntity {}
```

I know that I can use the type property to let Jackson know what to convert into a concrete type by having it as a property, but it must be inside the parent class for this to work.
Is there any way i can use the `type` property in `SkydropXApiResponse` to tell Jackson what concrete types it should deserialize POJOs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, I have found my answer!
Instead of adding `@JsonTypeInfo` annotations to my abstract class, I ended up adding them to the `attributes` property on my wrapper class.

```java
public class SkydropXApiResponse {
    private String id;
    private String type;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "parcels", value = SkydropXParcel.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "rates", value = SkydropXQuotation.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "addresses", value = SkydropXAddress.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "labels", value = SkydropXLabel.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "shipments", value = SkydropXShipment.class),
    })
    private SkydropXEntity attributes;

    public String getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getType() { return type; }

    public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }

    public SkydropXEntity getAttributes() { return attributes; }

    public void setAttributes(SkydropXEntity attributes) { this.attributes = attributes; }
}
```